# I want to color candle which is not touching 5EMA

Tags: view, pine-script, trading

I want to highlight candle which is not touching 5EMA in trading view. kindly help me with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)

EMA5 = ta.ema(close, 5)
bgcolor(low > EMA5 or high < EMA5 ? color.new(color.green, 90) : na)
```